# Append string at the end of a line with bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have some .yml file containing string like this

```
test_test_servicename: test-alpha
```

in which at the end I want to recursive append "-beta"

```
test_test_servicename: test-alpha-beta
```

I found a similar post here where they say to use:

```
sed '/^servicename:/ s/$/-beta/' file
```

but i dont know why it doesnt work in my case. If I remove `^` it works but the file is full of `^M` characters.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `sed` to parse YAML files. Use a syntax aware parser. can you use Python? and use its yaml module?

Comment: A caret `^` means the start of a line. You surely don't have `servicename` at the start of a line.

Comment: Sadly I cant use Python on this system...

Comment: `file is full of ^M` -> You need to use `dos2unix` to clean them up

Comment: Full of `^M` it's CRLF line ending which means the file is possibly generated or edited on a Windows machine. Use `dos2unix filename` to convert it to Unix line ending (LF only).

Comment: Is there a reason for using "servicename" in your regex, instead of "test_test_servicename"? I understand that the latter represents the targeted lines. Using the latter with a `^` would prevent the problem you currently have with the `^`.

Comment: yes servicename regex is mandatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see the file is "full of `^M`" is probably because you generated or last edited the file on a Windows machine, which uses CR+LF as line ending. `^M` is the CR (carriage return) character. Use this command to convert the file to Unix line ending (LF only) **before applying `sed` to it**.

```
dos2unix <your file>
```

---

```
sed '/servicename:/ s/$/-beta/' file
```

It's right. Drop the caret `^`.

In RegEx, a caret denotes **the beginning of a line**. So `^servicename:` will match these lines:

```
servicename: abc
servicename::::::
```

but not these lines

```
a servicename:
another servicename:
test-servicename: abc
```